# I'm getting an access control error

Tags: jquery, jquery-xml

Why am I getting this error when trying to read a remote xml feed?

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.companyname.com/external.php?type=xml. Origin http://intranet is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This is the script I am using to try to get the xml file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_xml_feed();

    function get_xml_feed() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.companyname.com/external.php?type=xml',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'xml',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function(xml) { 
                $(xml).find('items').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('guid');
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    var date = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
                    var url = $(this).find('link').text();

                    $('.divContent').empty().append(title + " - " + date + " - " + url + "<br />");
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). AJAX requests can be sent only to urls belonging on the same domain as the one hosting your script.

Typical workaround consist of setting up a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain and then send an AJAX request to this script that will delegate.

Another possibility is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) but this the remote domain must support it.

Comment: JSONP is the most genius hack ever.  +1

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I don't understand.  Why is it that applications like google reader can access that xml file, but I can't access it with jquery?

Comment: @oshirowanen, on which domain is this XML file hosted?

Comment: The xml file is on my website, imagine it's company.com.  I can use google reader to read that xml file.  But I cannot read that xml file from my intranet.

Comment: @oshirowanen, what makes you think that google reader uses AJAX to fetch this feed? As a matter of fact it doesn't.

Comment: @oshirowanen, **you cannot send AJAX requests to distant domains**. That's how it is. No matter what you try there's a policy in browsers which forbids it. So you may try one of the workarounds I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Can I use a intranet serverside language like php/aspx to retrieve the xml file to the intranet, then use ajax to get the local version of the file?

Comment: @oshirowanen, absolutely, that's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: You've also suggested JSONP, is that a better option?

Comment: @oshirowanen, JSONP is a very good option as it allows you to directly access the remote domain without an additional request. The drawback is that you need to have control over this remote domain. If you do have control and can modify the feed, JSONP is an excellent workaround the same origin policy.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov,  I do have control over the remote domain.  JSONP it is then!  Thanks for the help.